# Creating exe from a Python Directory

Tags: python, batch-file, exe

so I finished a project in python and now I wanna transfer the whole project into exe.
I have a couple directories in the project which makes it look like so :
[image]

My Main is in ServerStart and it has dependencies from all the other files in the directories.
how can I create 1 exe file that will run it all?

I tried using pyinstaller and failed miserable.
the command I used(already inside the projects directory)

```
pip install pyinstaller

cd ServerStart

pyinstaller --onefile ServerMain.py
```

Am I missing on something ? it just creates an exe that on click -and closes immediately , when I used pause in the batch , it seemed like the program didn't even start running  .

**python script**

[image]

Comment: It does nothing is simply not a good enough explanation of a reproducible issue. Your question seems more suited to a site which tutors you how to perform a task, not one which helps you to fix a specific issue with your provided code. You should probably take the [tour] and read through the linked pages of [ask], to better understand how this site works, paying some attention to [mcve]. Once done, if you feel that you can make your question a better fit here, please [edit] it, and also include the python script content `ServerMain.py`.

Comment: @Compo Thank u for pointing it out , I fixed the stuff u said in order to make the question more clear

Comment: It is clear, especially looking at your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566862/creating-exe-from-a-python-directory?noredirect=1#comment119427266_67566946), that you are indeed hoping for a tutor to walk you through how to perform a task. Your question is therefore not a fit for this site, and therefore off topic.

Comment: What you should do therefore is list the steps you took, exactly as you took them. This would allow willing helpers to both reproduce those steps, and possibly identify where yours failed, _(not to walk you through them all in order)_. Without doing so, you're expecting a tutor, not a diagnosis.

Comment: Wrapping a Python program into an executable is a good deal more complicated that you seem to realize. The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very helpful section called When things go wrong. I suggest you work through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/). I have used it once and it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: I have tried to use it and connect the entire folder into the ServerMain creation but it seemed to have no effect . would u mind publishing your step by step? maybe I missed something on the official guide